# Accessing an array at a variable index

Tags: arrays, mips, sieve-of-eratosthenes, mips32, sieve

I am brand new to MIPS and am attempting to write the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find all prime numbers from 1 to 1000. I am just following the steps outlined in 1-4, and not yet any of the refinements described.

Here is my code so far:

```
        .data
array:  .word   1:1000            # array[1000] = {1}   (assume all are prime initially)
length: .word   1000    
        .text
        .globl  main
main:   addi    $t0, $zero, 1       # $t0 = 1       (counter)
        la      $s0, length    # $s0 = &length
        lw      $s0, 0($s0)     # $s0 = length
        la      $t1, array         # $t1 = &array[0]
        lw      $t2, 0($t1)     # $t2 = array[0]
        addi    $t2, $t2, -1        # $t2 = 0
        sw      $t2, 0($t1)     # array[0] = $t2 = 0    (1 is not prime)
loop1:  beq     $t0, $s0, ToDo      # if counter == length...
        addi    $t0, $t0, 1     # counter++
        addi    $t1, $t1, 4     # $t1 = &array[counter]
        lw      $t2, 0($t1)     # $t2 = array[counter]
        beq     $t2, 0, loop1      # if $t2 is marked as not prime, move to next element
        addi    $t3, $zero, 1       # $t3 = 1       (multiplier)
        addi    $t4, $t0, 0     # $t4 = counter     (p)
loop2:  addi    $t3, $t3, 1     # multiplier++
        mul     $t4, $t4, $t3    # $t4 = $t4 * multiplier (2p, 3p, 4p...)
        bgt     $t4, $s0, loop1   # if $t4 >= length, go to outer loop
        la      $t5, $t4($t1)

ToDo:
```

I know that my last line is not valid. I am attempting to access the array at each index of 2p, 3p, 4p, etc. and set their values to `0` (not prime). How can I do this some other way? How can I access the array at a different index at each iteration of the loop?

**EDIT**

Here is my final solution upon reviewing Craig's answer below:
(apologies for the poor indenting - it doesn't copy well from my editor)

```
    .data
array:  
    .word   1:1000          # array of 1000 '1's - 1 = prime, 0 = not prime

length: 
    .word   1000            # length of array

primeArray:
    .word   0:200           # array of size 200 to store primes 

    .text
    .globl main

main:   addi    $s0, $zero, 0       # counter = 0
    la  $s1, length     # s1 = &length
    lw  $s1, 0($s1)     # s1 = length

    la  $t0, array      # t0 = &array[0]
    sw  $zero, 0($t0)       # array[0] = 0 -> '1' is not prime

outerLoop:
    beq $s0, $s1, gatherPrimes  # if counter == length
    addi    $s0, $s0, 1     # counter++
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4     # t0 = &array[counter]
    lw  $t1, 0($t0)     # t1 = array[counter]
    beq $t1, $zero, outerLoop   # if array[counter] is already not prime, continue
    addi    $t2, $s0, 1     # t2 = counter + 1
    addi    $t3, $t2, 0     # t3 = t2

innerLoop:
    add $t3, $t3, $t2       # t3 = t3 + t2
    bgt     $t3, $s1, outerLoop # if t3 > length, break
    addi    $t4, $t3, -1        # t4 = t3 - 1
    la  $t5, array      # t5 = &array[0]
    sll $t6, $t4, 2     # t6 = t4 * 4 (offset)
    add $t5, $t5, $t6       # t5 = &array[t3]
    sw  $zero, 0($t5)       # array[t3] = 0 -> not prime
    j   innerLoop

gatherPrimes:
    addi    $s0, $zero, 0       # counter = 0
    addi    $s2, $zero, 0       # primeCounter = 0
    la  $t0, array      # t0 = &array[0]
    la  $t2, primeArray     # t2 = &primeArray[0]

loop:   
    beq $s0, $s1, exit      # if counter == length, exit
    lw  $t1, 0($t0)     # t1 = array[counter]
    addi    $s0, $s0, 1     # counter++
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4     # t0 = &array[counter]  
    beq $t1, $zero, loop    # if array[i] is not prime, break
    sw  $s0, 0($t2)     # primeArray[primeCounter] = counter
    addi    $s2, $s2, 1     # primeCounter++
    addi    $t2, $t2, 4     # t2 = &primeArray[primeCounter]
    j   loop

exit:   
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I couldn't make sense of your program relative to the wiki linked algorithm.

In step (3) of the wiki, it indexes the array by multiples of `p`, marking each element as non-prime. `loop1` didn't do that.

It seems `loop1` was doing step (4) and then `loop2` would be doing step (3). This is actually okay to do in reverse order.

I created two programs starting from yours. I tried to remain faithful, but had to refactor a fair bit. One that adheres to the order of steps in the wiki. And, a second one that reverses the order.

To simplify things, I maintained an "end-of-array" pointer rather than a count. And, used a `.byte` array instead of a `.word` to simplify the indexing as the array is only used as a boolean vector [for larger arrays, with some extra code, it could be converted to a bit vector].

---

Here's the wiki version:

```
    .data
array:      .byte       1:1000
earray:
# array[1000] = {1}   (assume all are prime initially)

msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

    .text
    .globl  main

# registers:
#   s0 -- address of array
#   s1 -- address of end of array
#
#   t0 -- value of array[current]
#   t1 -- pointer to current array value being tested
#   t2 -- current "p" value
main:
    la      $s0,array               # get &array[0]
    la      $s1,earray              # get pointer to end of array
    sb      $zero,0($s0)            # 0 is not prime
    sb      $zero,1($s0)            # 1 is not prime

    li      $t2,2                   # p = 2
    move    $t1,$s0                 # get &array[0]
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # get &array[2]
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # get &array[4]
    j       mark_start

    # mark 2p, 3p, ... as not prime
mark_loop:
    sb      $zero,0($t1)            # mark as not prime
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # advance to next cell
mark_start:
    blt     $t1,$s1,mark_loop       # done with this p? if no, loop

    # find next higher prime than p
    addu    $t1,$s0,$t2             # get &array[p]
    addiu   $t1,$t1,1               # get &array[p + 1]
    j       find_start

find_loop:
    lb      $t0,0($t1)              # is current number [still] prime?
    bnez    $t0,find_match          # yes, fly
    addiu   $t1,$t1,1               # no, advance to next cell
find_start:
    blt     $t1,$s1,find_loop       # over edge? if no, loop
    j       print_all               # yes, sieve complete

    # found new p value -- set up to restart marking loop
find_match:
    sub     $t2,$t1,$s0             # get the new p value
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # get &array[2p]
    j       mark_start              # restart the marking loop

    # print all the primes
print_all:
    move    $t1,$s0                 # get array start
    li      $t2,0                   # get p value

print_loop:
    bge     $t1,$s1,main_exit       # over edge? if yes, exit program
    lb      $t0,0($t1)              # is current value prime?
    bnez    $t0,print_match         # if yes, fly

print_next:
    addi    $t1,$t1,1               # advance to next array element
    addiu   $t2,$t2,1               # increment p
    j       print_loop

print_match:
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall
    j       print_next

main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

Here's the one that reverses the steps:

```
    .data
array:      .byte       1:1000
earray:
# array[1000] = {1}   (assume all are prime initially)

msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

    .text
    .globl  main

# registers:
#   s0 -- address of array
#   s1 -- address of end of array
#
#   t0 -- value of array[current]
#   t1 -- pointer to current array value being tested
#   t2 -- current "p" value
main:
    la      $s0,array               # get &array[0]
    la      $s1,earray              # get pointer to end of array
    sb      $zero,0($s0)            # 0 is not prime
    sb      $zero,1($s0)            # 1 is not prime

    li      $t2,1                   # p = 1

    # find next higher prime than p
find_begin:
    move    $t1,$s0                 # get &array[0]
    addu    $t1,$s0,$t2             # get &array[p]
    addiu   $t1,$t1,1               # get &array[p + 1]
    j       find_start

find_loop:
    lb      $t0,0($t1)              # is current number [still] prime?
    bnez    $t0,find_match          # yes, fly
    addiu   $t1,$t1,1               # no, advance to next cell
find_start:
    blt     $t1,$s1,find_loop       # over edge? if no, loop
    j       print_all               # yes, sieve complete

    # found new p value -- set up to restart marking loop
find_match:
    sub     $t2,$t1,$s0             # get the new p value
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # get &array[2p]
    j       mark_start              # restart the marking loop

    # mark 2p, 3p, ... as not prime
mark_loop:
    sb      $zero,0($t1)            # mark as not prime
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t2             # advance to next cell (2p, 3p, 4p, ...)
mark_start:
    blt     $t1,$s1,mark_loop       # done with this p? if no, loop
    j       find_begin

    # print all the primes
print_all:
    move    $t1,$s0                 # get array start
    li      $t2,0                   # get p value

print_loop:
    bge     $t1,$s1,main_exit       # over edge? if yes, exit program
    lb      $t0,0($t1)              # is current value prime?
    bnez    $t0,print_match         # if yes, fly

print_next:
    addi    $t1,$t1,1               # advance to next array element
    addiu   $t2,$t2,1               # increment p
    j       print_loop

print_match:
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall
    j       print_next

main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply, and apologies for only getting back to you now. I reviewed your solutions upon being overly confused by my own. I decided to start a fresh (and did so several times as I made progress, but my method became too messy) and have reached my solution which works reasonably well. I have added it to my initial post